# How to calculate minimum number of swap to make the median of two sorted arrays equal?

Tags: median

```
1 2 3 3 5 6 7 

4 6 8 8 9 9 9
```

We just need two swap operations.

**First swap operation:**

Take 1 from A and 9 from B and swap them.

Now the arrays look like this: `A = [2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]` and `B = [1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9]`.

**Second swap operation:**

Take 2 from A and 9 from B and swap them.

Now the arrays look like this: `A = [3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9]` and `B = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 9]`.

Now the median of both arrays is 6.

Comment: if you got the answer. please post.